# Express Http request timeout

Tags: node.js, http, express, websocket

I have a question about socket timeout in NodeJs.

In a first time, I add the folowing code :

```
    req.socket.once('timeout', function(err) {
        imports.logger.warn('Express socket timeout.', err);
        res.status(504).end('Connection timeout');
    });
```

And I have often Express Socket timeout error logged in console a long time after the page loaded.
So (for debugging) I try to add this line :

```
    req.socket.setTimeout(4000);
```

And finally I saw that all my request handle a Express socket timeout after 4 seconds.
I search on the web and I found a lot of information but I still don't understand.

I don't understand why res.json() function that close the request does not also close the socket. Is there a link with keep-alive ? A link with web socket ?

If it's a link to web socket what is the best pratice ? Should I close the socket and (if yes) where exactly ?

If necessary you can see my simple Express route code :

```
 app.get(apiUrl + '/:id', function (req, res) {

    NewsFeed.findById(req.params.id, function (err, newsFeed) {

        if (err) {
            return app.error(res, 404, 'Error 404: No news found');
        }

        res.json(formatNewsFeed(newsFeed));

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP, there is no requirement that you have a strict one-one mapping of socket to request. When it is possible, the browser and server will keep the socket around after the request has finished so that it can be re-used in later requests. Opening a new socket takes time and it can be faster to be able to reuse an existing socket. This is called HTTP Keep-Alive. Generally you do not need to worry about the underlying sockets and only work with the request object.

Comment: Ok thanks. But I'm not sure that is a normal behaviour for expressjs to throw a socket timeout exception. In my others project I never had this problem with expressjs.